Optional stochastic sets of interval type
I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 8.17 in Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus by He, Wang, and Yan.
In the proof (Eq. 17.2) it claims that
$$
T(\omega) = \inf\{t : (\omega, t) \in B^\complement\}, 
$$
is a stopping time, where $B$ is an optional set of interval type (the definition and details are given below).

Is there a way for $T$ to be a stopping time without the usual conditions and only based on the set $B$ being an optional set of interval type? or the usual conditions are assumed implicitly by the authors.

If we assume the stochastic basis satisfies the usual conditions then it is clear that $T$ is a stopping time: $B$ is optional so both $B$ and $B^\complement$ are progressive, the filtration is complete so by the debut theorem, $T$ is optional (wide-sense stopping)  time, and the filtration is right-continuous so $T$ is a stopping time. However, the book does not explicitly mention that it assumes the usual conditions in this section.
For completeness, here is the relevant parts from the book:
Definition 8.16, a $B \subset \Omega \times \mathbb{R}_+$ is called a set of interval type if there is a non-negative r.v. $T$ such that for each $\omega$ the section $B_\omega$ is $[0,T(\omega)[$ or $[0,T(\omega)]$ and $B_\omega \neq \emptyset$.
8.17 Theorem: $B$ is an optional set of interval type if and only if
$$
I_B = I_F I_{[0,T[} + I_{F^c} I_{[0,T]},
$$
where $T$ is a stopping time, $F \in \mathcal{F}_T$ and $T_F > 0$.
Proof. The sufficiency is trivial. We want to show the necessity. Put
$$
T(\omega) = \inf\{t : (\omega, t) \in B^\complement\}, \tag{17.2}
$$
$$
F = \{\omega : T(\omega) < \infty, (\omega, T(\omega)) \in B^\complement\}. \tag{17.3}
$$
Then $T$ is a stopping time. Since $I_F = 1 \iff I_{B^\complement}(T) I_{[T < \infty]} = 1$, we have $F \in \mathcal{F}_T$. Now it is easy to verify (17.1)
